# Sendmail delays on some email addresses

Tags: php, email, sendmail

On our webserver, the PHP `mail()` command consistently hangs on some email addresses but is fine with the majority. It hangs for over 2 mins, by which time the PHP script has lost connection with the DB so returns an error to the browser.

We use *sendmail* and I can see a delay of 2:36 in the mail log (*/var/log/maillog*) for the email address that causes the problem:

```
Dec  9 11:24:00 liveserver sendmail[12666]: nB9BLOHa012666: to=***blanked_out***, delay=00:02:36, mailer=esmtp, pri=31326, dsn=4.4.3, stat=queued
```

It is easy to reproduce the problem. I can put the email I want to test in the following command:

```
echo "Test message from sendmail." | sendmail -ffromtest@test.com problem@problememail.com
```

Most email address cause the command to return within 1s (including invalid email addresses). But the problematic email address hangs for 2:36.

- Why doesn't sendmail queue the message and return immediately so PHP can continue running?
- Does anyone have any tips for debugging the issue?
- Does anyone have any tips on how to probe the problematic email address to see why it is causing a delay?

*Note:* We currently have 550 messages queued - but this number is not above normal (`find /var/spool/mqueue -type f -name qf\* -print|wc -l|tr -d ' '`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically email delays are DNS problems.

Try running:

```
host -t mx problemdomain.com
```

If that doesn't seem to be the problem, use `sendmail -bi -v` to get more debugging output.

Comment: Thank you, yes seems to be a DNS issue - `host -t mx problemdomain.com`

    ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

I guess I need to find the sendmail option to timeout quicker for DNS issues.

Comment: After an hour of trying to find the sendmail DNS timeout period myself, I thought it wouldn't be too lazy to get help? http://serverfault.com/questions/92603/how-to-reduce-the-sendmail-dns-timeout-period

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps its dns issue, try doing a dig problemmail.com.

You could also try strace and se what the process does:

attach to the process:
    strace -ff -s 512 -v -p pid 

start the process with strace:
    strace -ff -s 512 -v sendmail -ffromtest...........

add -o ~/sendmail.strace for output into a file.

-ff makes it follow forks

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own questions (in case it's useful to others):

> *Why doesn't sendmail queue the message and return immediately so PHP can continue running?*

It should do. If it doesn't it means the DNS server setup is broken. Normally DNS lookups are quick - A query on a non-existing MX/domain should receive a NXDOMAIN response within milli-seconds. It should not wait such a long time - this issue is probably causing other problems with many programs, e.g. sshd and NFS?

> *Does anyone have any tips for debugging the issue?*

Try running:

```
host -t mx problemdomain.com
```

Then run it again using googleDNS (IP address of 8.8.8.8) instead of the current DNS service:

```
host -t mx problemdomain.com 8.8.8.8
```

If there is a difference, it means the current DNS server setup is broken. Check the nameservers in */etc/resolv.conf* and perhaps raise a issue ticket with the hosting company or whoever supplies the nameservers you are using?

As a temporary workaround, try adding a DNS timeout in */etc/resolv.conf*:

```
timeout: n
    sets the amount of time (in seconds) the resolver will wait for a response from a remote name server before retrying the query via a different name server.
```

> *Does anyone have any tips on how to probe the problematic email address to see why it is causing a delay?*

Try `dig`, a DNS lookup utility and monitor the status code. e.g. NOERROR for success, NXDOMAIN for not found, etc:

```
dig problemdomain.com
```

Try `nslookup`, a program to query Internet name servers:

```
nslookup problemdomain.com
```

Try timing the `sendmail` command and use `-bi -v` to get more info:

```
time echo "This is a test message" | /usr/lib/sendmail -bi -v -ftest@test.com test@problemdomain.com
```